# Calculating probabilities of completing a trading card/collector card set

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, combinatorics

I'm looking at creating a set of collector cards (think baseball cards). I'm worried about the statistics and would like some help if possible.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say the basics are:

- There are ten different card designs
- Cards are available in packs of five
- Each card in a pack is unique (no duplicates)
- The availability of each card is equal (no card is rarer than another)

What worries me is that a collector receiving their first pack already has 50% of the complete set! It presumably wouldn't take them long to get the rest.

So I'd like to calculate what the probability is of collecting all ten designs in 2 packs, 3 packs, 4 packs, etc

I can actually figure out the two-pack probability fairly easily, because if you got cards 1,2,3,4,5 in pack 1, then pack 2 would need to be 6,7,8,9,10 (1/10 * 1/9 * 1/8 * 1/7 * 1/6 = 1/30240, with 120 possible combinations = 120/30240 = 0.4%, right?).

But figuring out the probability of collecting all ten designs in 3 packs is eluding me because there are so many ways of getting them (4 in the second pack/1 in the third, 3/2, 2/3, 1/4, 0/5 etc) and then four packs is even more involved.

It feels like I'm trying to calculate the probability of combinations of combinations of combinations!

Is there a methodology by which to do these calculations? Maybe even an online calculator or code? I'm not a statistician by any means, so I'm not even sure what to search for. If someone could give me some pointers, it would be much appreciated.

I can do basic Python coding and have access to (though little experience of) R if that would help.

Comment: For much more about this class of problems, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector.

Comment: That's awesome. Many thanks. Guess if I searched for "sticker" and not "card" I might have found it. Doh!

Comment: Believe it or not, I searched for "Pannini" :-).